# Assertion Results Changing / Inconsistent Assertion Statements

Tags: apex, failing-tests

Team,

I have a VERY odd problem. When I observe the test results, through an assertion the results change each time the test is run.  The result should be 4, so I have the following statement:

```
system.assertEquals(4,xInvoice.lineItems.size());
```

However, when I run the test I get the following error:

```
"System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 4, Actual: 3"

Class.test_xeroSync.sfXero_xeroSf: line 34, column 1
```

So, I changed the assertion to:

```
system.assertEquals(3,xInvoice.lineItems.size());
```

When I re-run the test I get this error:

```
System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected: 3, Actual: 4

Class.test_xeroSync.sfXero_xeroSf: line 34, column 1
```

I am running the tests within 30 seconds of each other.  I am the only developer and no other code changes are being made between times.

Has anyone else seen this?  I raised a case with Sf.com Premier Support over a week ago, but as usual they haven't responded!  Can anyone help?

Comment: A PERFECT Example why you should be using asserts to test outcome and not just cover lines. Something is not working as expected, now lets see if we can help you figure out what..`In order to do so, we need to see the code you are referring to.` Oh, and WHY would you change the assert?? The expected outcome should not CHANGE so why would you change what is expected to get the test to pass. You might as well just remove the assert and keep the ineffective code...

Comment: I suspect either seeAlldata=true or there is a use of math.random..can you share your code and test code

Comment: Other possibility is an older API version set for the class, therefore using org data. As @Eric pointed out, we need more code.